# Determine the convergence being,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis

Be,
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^{n}},\hspace{5mm}\forall x\geq0$$
what I want is to graph that function, but as I do analytically, because for $ n = 0 $ and $ n = 1 $ are a line and a hyperbole, but then while the $ n \rightarrow \infty $ 'apparently' $ f (x) \rightarrow0 $

Comment: for $0 \le x \lt 1$, $f(x) = x$ and for $x \ge 1$, $f(x) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for $x \ge 0$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x < 1$} \\
1, & \text{if $x = 1$} \\
+\infty, & \text{if $x > 1$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Now clearly $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^n} =  \begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x < 1$} \\
\frac12, & \text{if $x = 1$} \\
0, & \text{if $x > 1$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I apologize and how can I prove the trend for $x^{n}$ as well as how intuitive it is not.

Comment: @SantiagoSeeker If $x < 1$ then the sequence $(x^n)_n$ is decreasing and bounded from below by $0$ so it converges to a limit $L$. We have $x^{n+1} = x \cdot x^n$ so letting $n\to\infty$ gives $L = x \cdot L$ so $L = 0 $. If $x = 1$ then $(x^n)_n$ is just a sequence of ones. If $x > 1$ then check that for any $M > 0$ we have $x^n \ge M$ whenever $n \ge \frac{\ln M}{\ln x}$.